# How to get rid of empty cells in an importrange and sort by person?

Tags: google-sheets, null, importrange

I am importing data to display form multiple sheets. I'm able to get the data, but I want to eliminate any empty cells. How do I get rid of blank columns and sort by person name?

```
=Query({IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","January!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","February!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","March!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","April!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","May!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","June!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","June!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","July!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","August!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","September!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","October!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","November!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","December!A:Z")},"select Col3 * where Col3 <> " ") and Where Col2 = “Mike”
```

Comment: any example of the data? anyway, you might have better luck on [webapps stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

- for removing empty cells you need to add: **`is not null`** and choose a column.
- for sorting you need to add **`order by`** and choose a column.

example:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","January!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","February!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","March!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","April!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","May!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","June!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","June!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","July!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","August!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","September!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","October!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","November!A:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","December!A:Z")},
 "select * 
  where Col3 <> '' 
    and Col2 = 'Mike'
    and Col1 is not null
  order by Col4 desc")
```